# Find and replace in a file without reading file as a string

Tags: perl, file, replace

**My Question:** If I'm given `C:\text_file.txt` as a parameter on the command line when my PERL script is called and the `text_file.txt` contains the text "Hello World World World", how do I replace all instances of "World" with "Earth"?

I'm new to PERL. I'm writing a script which accepts a parameter of a filepath. I want to do a find replace on the contents of the file. I know I could do something like this: `$string =~ s/World/Earth/g;` but I don't want to read the file into a string if I can help it. Is there a way to do this directly on the file without reading it in as a string? Thanks!

Comment: You're always going to be reading the file into a string. Although, not necessarily the whole thing at once. A line at a time is fine.

Comment: I realize that. I'm just wanting to abstract it so I don't have to worry about it. I'm looking for a built-in way that PERL already has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what Perl's `-i` ("inplace edit") switch is for:

```
$ perl -i.bak -pe 's/World/Earth/g' text_file.txt
```

EDIT: To incorporate this identical functionality into a larger Perl script:

```
{
    local $^I = '.bak';
    local @ARGV = ('text_file.txt');
    local $_;
    while (<>) {
        s/World/Earth/g;
        print;
    }
}
```

The `$^I` variable reflects the value of the `-i` command-line switch; here, it's being set manually.  Also, `@ARGV` is being manually set to the list of files that would ordinarily be taken from the command line.  The whole thing is wrapped in a block so that `$^I` and `@ARGV`, set with `local`, resume their original values afterwards; this may not be strictly necessary, depending on the rest of the program.  I also localized `$_` just to keep the `while` loop from clobbering the value it previously held; this also may not be necessary.

Note that you can use just `-i` instead of `-i.bak` from the command line if you want to avoid creating a backup file.  The corresponding code would be `$^I = ""` instead of `$^I = '.bak'`.

Comment: How do I add that to a PERL script? (Like I said, I'm pretty new)

Comment: In this case, `s/World/Earth/g` **is** the Perl script.